# Sphero: Getting bolt to move based on distance programmed?

Tags: mit-scratch, sphero

I am having trouble getting Bolt to stop moving after moving 5cm (It is not stopping). Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image: Blocks]

Comment: I don't know sphero but I would guess that you should use `>=` instead of `===` as it would be merely a coincidence if your code runs at the exact moment when it is at 5cm.

Comment: Is `distance` continuously being updated as Bolt moves? Then you also need to continuously test it. It seems you only test it once; your code may need a loop (or even better, a 'wait until' block instead of 'if').

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.